# jquery code is not working in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

**This code is working fine and loads the advertisement**

```
<script type="text/javascript">google_ad_client = 'ca-pub-1702577941194110';</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
```

**jquery does not work and it is under wordpress plugin code.**

```
jQuery('#addSpace').html("") 
.append("<script type='text/javascript'>"+" google_ad_client ='"+this.title+"'"+ " </" + "script>"+"<script type='text/javascript' src='http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js'>"+"</" + "script>");
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: and so ? do you have jquery loaded (via script tag). What does error console say ? (f12 in chrome, then console tab and check for errors)

Comment: isn't `jQuery()` deprecated or is `$()` just shorthand?

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers don't update changes to HTML this way. It's better to do it with inbuilt fns.

Try,

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js';
$('#addSpace').append( script );
```

From: http://mg.to/2006/01/25/json-for-jquery

Comment: function onAfter() { 
jQuery('#output').html("") 
.append('<h3><a href="#" title="">' + this.id + '</a><p>'+ this.alt +'</p></h3>');
            
var google_ad_client = this.title;          
google_ad_client = "google_ad_client = '"+google_ad_client+"';";                      
$('#addSpace').html("<script type='text/javascript'>" +google_ad_client+"</" + "script>");
            
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src ='http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js';
$('#addSpace').html(script);
}
Use in this way but not working.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like google_ad_client should in the first script is just a variable so you should assign this first

```
var google_ad_client = $('#addSpace').attr('title');
```

then create the second script to append to the element

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js';
$('#addSpace').html(script);
```

Comment: function onAfter() { 
jQuery('#output').html("") 
.append('<h3><a href="#" title="">' + this.id + '</a><p>'+ this.alt +'</p></h3>');
            
var google_ad_client = this.title;          
google_ad_client = "google_ad_client = '"+google_ad_client+"';";                      
$('#addSpace').html("<script type='text/javascript'>" +google_ad_client+"</" + "script>");
            
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src ='http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js';
$('#addSpace').html(script);
}
Use in this way but not working.